# Do solution and programs from different Linux distributions work?

Tags: linux, debian

I am looking for a brightness Controller GUI(As in a GUI to increase my brightness using a slider) for Debian OS. However, every solution I have found are for Ubuntu and Mint. Since they are derivatives, do these solutions work regardless of the Linux version?

Edit:
While reading through [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/backlight), it turns out "brightness is controlled by vendor-specified hotkey and there is no interface for the OS to adjust the brightness". Since I am using a Raspberry PI on a monitor, I can't use the keyboard to adjust the light. Let me know if this is correct.

Comment: Probably depends on your windowing system/manager/gui (idk exactly the right terms, but something for KDE may not look/work right on GTK). Also, what’s a brightness controller? Explaining that and why you need a gui for it might get you a long way. Use the [edit] button to add details

Comment: Please don't create duplicate questions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am new to Stackexchange & Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on compatibility.  The following solutions are all on the command-line, though you could bind these to a key combination (AKA a hotkey):

- Install [`acpilight`](https://security.archlinux.org/package/acpilight) or `xbacklight`.
- Run `echo X > /sys/class/backlight/Y/brightness`, where `X` is the brightness (e.g. `1500`), and `Y` is your backlight device (e.g. `intel_backlight`; this version automatically detects `Y`: `echo X > $(find /sys/class/backlight/* -maxdepth 1)/brightness`).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Desktop-Environment, but since you are using Debian, you probably search for a GUI in GNOME. Since that it's already integrated in GNOME, you just have to open the activites overview, than type in 'power' and open the application. In the application there should be a brightness slider, which you can use to change your display brightness.

source: https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/display-brightness.html.it

Comment: There are no "activities overview" in Debian 10